# Bug Cordova 1.5 Can't find variable: PhoneGap

Tags: ios, xcode4, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I use a plugin of FTP Transfert under Cordova 1.5
But when i called to the function, an error appear : Can't find variable: PhoneGap.

the JS Script of the plugin contain :

```
return Cordova.exec(success, fail, "FTPPlugin", "upload", types);
```

I don't know where is the variable PhoneGap which appear in the error

Environnement:

> Mac Os X Version 10.6.8 Build 10K549
>
> Xcode Version 4.0.2 Build 4A2002a
>
> Cordova 1.5

Comment: Did you add your plugin to your file `cordova.plist`?

Comment: yes i add it, and the problem is resolved . I change #import <CORDOVA/CDVPlugin.h> with #import <CORDOVA/CDV.h>
but another problem appear when i use the library "SCRFTPRequest.h" 
Error occurred.
Upload failed: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)

Comment: :O oh ok then... Good for you mate ^^

Answer (score 0):

You must have a problem of version between Cordova and Phonegap version.
"Can't find variable: PhoneGap"

You can try to replace PhoneGap with Cordova to verify.